A novel about people most of whom are more or less color blind
I'm not sure when I read this novel, and I remember very little of it. But it was least 10 years ago, probably more.
I don't remember any event of the story.
All I remember is that most people lacked at least one type of colour receptors (these receptors were supposed to detect the "elementary colours", red, yellow, blue when in fact it is red, green and blue, but it is  SF, not actual science !), often two or three.  So people who lacked none were on top of the society, those lacking only one were just below, and were called by the "mixed" color complementary to the lacking one (those lacking "red" were "green", etc.) Those who had only one were even below, and called by the name of that color. At the bottom of society where those seeing just in black and white.
This oppressive system certainly deserves the name of dystopia.

Shades of Grey by Jasper Fforde.

Hundreds of years in the future, the world is an alarmingly different place. Life is lived according to The Rulebook and social hierarchy is determined by your perception of colour.
Eddie Russett is an above-average Red who dreams of moving up the ladder. Until he is sent to the Outer Fringes where he meets Jane - a lowly Grey with an uncontrollable temper and a desire to see him killed.
For Eddie, it's love at first sight. But his infatuation will lead him to discover that all is not as it seems in a world where everything that looks black and white is really shades of grey...

The SF reading group that I belong to discussed it about ten years ago and I remember it vividly (pun intended). Jasper Fforde writes very English fantasy, which suits me fine as I'm a very English Englishman.
The oppressive system is a thinly disguised version of the English class system that I remember from my childhood (it is now a thing of the past, and good riddance). Whether England in the 1950s and 60s was a dystopia is a matter of opinion.
If you enjoyed it note that the sequel Red Side Story has just been released.

Thanks a lot for your info about the sequel. I do remember now that it ended on a cliffhanger and I was expecting a sequel, but after some time I just  gave up to the point of forgetting the name of the author. Fifteen years !

Fforde commented at the time that Shades of Grey didn't sell as well as books from his other series and he had to prioritise paying the rent so he couldn't justify writing a follow up immediately. I'm glad he's finally got round to the sequel now, and it's on my tablet awaiting my attention.

And in the unlikely case that it matters to your enjoyment of the story, note that the real-world color sensing compounds in the human eye are not red/green/blue.  It's complicated, but anyhow the RGB triplet is a convenient external set of stimuli to "fool" the eye but not how the eye really works.

@Ethan The reactivity of each type of cone in function of the wavelength is easy to find. True the maximum of the "red" cones is at the green-yellow limit, but they are the only ones that extend far into the red zone. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B4ne_(photor%C3%A9cepteur)#/media/Fichier:Spectre_absorption_des_cones.svg

The sequel is here ?  amagod, amagod, amagod... I losted hope...

@Ethan There's some indications that the characters aren't exactly human, or at least not humans as we know them. (e.g. one of the big reveals is that colors can do things to them which would be physiologically impossible for "normal" humans.) -- I anticipate that's something Fforde will explore in the sequels.
